# Change a header's position from fixed to relative on opening (active) mobile drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a responsive design that when viewed on a device less than `600px` wide, uses drop down multi-level navigation. It is nested inside a header that is set to `position: fixed`. The problem is, that when you drop down the menu the menu overflows downward and does not scroll (because the header is fixed), so the tabs are not visible. Is there a way (using Javascript, jQuery or PHP) to dynamically set it so that when the drop down menu (by way of clicking on the hamburger menu icon in the top right or left), it changes the header's position from `fixed` to `relative`?

A good example would be www.dribbble.com. When it's less than `800px` wide, the header is sticky (`fixed`), then when you click on the menu in the top left, it's obvious that the header's position automatically changes to `relative`.

### HTML

```
    <header role="banner" class="secondary">
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-toggle"><em>Menu</em> <span aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu set">
    <li class="subnav">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

### CSS

```
header[role="banner"] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    z-index: 10000; 
}

@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
    header[role="banner"] {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        clear: both;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 499px) {
    header[role="banner"] {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

### JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('body').addClass('js');
      var $menu = $('#nav'),
          $menulink = $('.menu-toggle'),
          $menuTrigger = $('.subnav > a');

$menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
});

var add_toggle_links = function() {         
    if ($('.menu-toggle').is(":visible")){
        if ($(".toggle-link").length > 0){
        }
        else{
            $('.subnav > a').before('<span class="toggle-link">Open</span>');
            $('.toggle-link').click(function(e) {       
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.toggleClass('active').siblings('ul').toggleClass('active');
            }); 
        }
    }
    else{
        $('.toggle-link').empty();
    }
 }
add_toggle_links();
$(window).bind("resize", add_toggle_links); 

    });
```

Comment: show your code .. We cant help without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a custom id or some other kind of attribute for a selector than you can change the `position` CSS property in multiple ways.

### CSS3

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
   header[role="banner"] {
      position: relative;
   }
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
       if ($( document ).width() < 499)
          $('header[role="banner"]').css('position', 'relative');
       else
          $('header[role="banner"]').css('position', 'fixed');
    });
});
```

---

**Note:** You edited your post. Did you realized that you used `position: fixed;` in both of your CSS `@media` rules? Change the second to `position: relative;`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but it did not work. I need the header[role="banner"] position: fixed to change to position: relative when the #hamburger-icon menu is clicked only. So the header will be fixed, but when the menu is clicked, everything scrolls.

Comment: Okay, I did that, changed the max-width: 499px to position: relative, but it still does not work.

Comment: The jQuery code you provided does not work. The header needs to change from position: fixed to position: relative ONLY when viewed on a device less than 499 px, AND the .menu-toggle link is clocked, so essentially when the menu is activated.

Comment: @user2485157 According to your code I updated the jQuery solution and the CSS as well. Both of them work for me. Use only one of them.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, that worked. However, when you click on the menu again, the header remains at position: relative. Is there a way to include the rule in the jQuery so if the menu-toggle link is clicked again (closing the menu), the header returns to the position: fixed? I also  notice a flicker, so let's say you scroll half way down the page with the header fixed, then click on the menu to open it, the page sort of jumps. And the header disappears off the page, but it really is at the top, but relative. Does this make sense?

Comment: @user2485157 You can get the actual value of the `position` property by omitting the second parameter: `$('header[role="banner"]').css('position');` just check the actual value in an `if()`.

Comment: Not sure how you would do that.

Comment: I still need the header to be position: relative. I just don't want the page to jump if a user is let's say in the middle of a page and then decides to click on the menu, and it "jumps".

Comment: And also, when you click on the menu again, the header remains at position: relative. Is there a way to include the rule in the jQuery so if the menu-toggle link is clicked again (closing the menu), the header returns to the position: fixed?

Comment: @user2485157 Use the CSS solution only. It will do all of this in the background, so you don't have to mess with jQuery. If you have problems with it, please ask it in a new question. Thats the way we do it here.